# ¿Cómo ocultar un navbar, mostrar el otro y desplegar el menú al hacer clic?

Tags: jquery

Tengo dos Navbar, uno para la PC y el otro para el responsive, de hecho funciona, pero al estar en el móvil necesito que al hacer clic en el botón `$(".navbar-toggler")` cambie por el otro navbar dark, y además despliege el menú simultáneamente... Tengo el siguiente código y funciona pero debo dar dos clic (uno para que cambie al menú dark y otro para que despliegue el menú. Mi intensión es que al hacer clic cambie y despliegue, este es el código que funciona:

```
$(".navbar-toggler").click(function() {
   $('#menuSmall').show();
   $('#menuLarge').hide();
});
```

Me imagino que hay que agregar este código `$(".navbar-toggler").trigger('click');` pero no sé como unirlo a `$('#menuSmall').show();` para que muestre el menuSmall y además se despliege el menú simultaneamente.

Comment: Para que funcione das dos veces al mismo boton?

Comment: Actualmente sí, necesito que con el primer clic, cambie el menú y se despliegue simultaneamente.

Comment: Es que no veo el porque funciona al hacer dos clicks

Comment: Al hacer el primer clic muestra este nav -> $('#menuSmall').show(); y oculta este otro -> $('#menuLarge').hide(); luego el segundo es para desplegar el menú

Comment: Pero no nos estas mostrando el segundo click entonces

Comment: Los menus son iguales, solo cambia el color, tengo el menú blanco, cuando hago clic en el se muestra el negro... A eso corresponde el código publicado... Lo que yo requiero es que al hacer clic en en botón del menú cambie de color como lo hace pero adicionalmente despliege el menú.